# Не могу выполнить на Python проверку в setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, инкапсуляция

Есть следующее задание:

1. Написать класс, который описывает пользователя (class User), сделать ему приватный
   атрибут age, который передается в конструктор, публичный атрибут name, который так же
   передается в конструктор.
2. Написать getter и setter для атрибута age.
3. Добавить в setter проверку на валидный возраст (не отрицательное, целое число).

С первыми двумя справился, а в третьем задании пробовал через if...else statement, но не получилось.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.__age = age
        self.name = name

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.__age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value != int:
            self.__age = "Use only integer numbers"
        elif value < 0:
            self.__age = "Use only positive numbers"
        else:
            self.__age = value

user1 = User(age=25, name="John")
user1.age = -5.5
print(user1.age)
```

Comment: вы бы написали, что хотели получить, что получили. Что значит "не получилось"?

Comment: хотелось бы получить следующее: при user1.age = -5 (к примеру) -> use only positive numbers, при user1.age = 5.5 -> use only integers numbers

Comment: Замените `value != int` на `type(value) != int`. Только какой смысл присваивать значение полю в этом случае? Нужно бросать исключение `raise ValueError('Use only integer')`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Вспомнил, что в блоке try...except предусмотрен raise